# How to fully reset all Visual Studio settings to factory defaults?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio 2022 installed.

This is Community Edition, I am logged in and registered with my Microsoft Account.
It is important.

I removed all "Visual Studio*" directories in my "C:\Users*".

After restarting Visual Studio it immediately shows the dialog to log into my Microsoft Account. I log in and then it imports some of my previous settings. For example - my old color theme is applied. The one particular offending setting than doesn't show in UI is still set.

I'm afraid that uninstalling and reinstalling the program won't help either.

The setting I want to change is "Enable new Project Properties UI" - it was available in 2022 Preview 1. After upgrading to 2022 Preview 2 it disappeared from the settings dialog and the Project Properties dialog crashes. I'm stuck with broken Preview 2 but I know if I reset the settings it would work. The problem is I don't know how to reset settings so they would not be recovered from the cloud.

I tried so far:

- `devenv /ResetSettings`
- resetting the settings with Import/Export menu
- resetting the settings from Visual Studio Installer Repair option

None of those actions even changed my theme from dark to light.

Comment: Don't know if it still works or not. On the command prompt run `devenv.exe /ResetSettings`.

Comment: [Visual Studio : Reset All Settings](https://www.technipages.com/visual-studio-reset-all-settings).

Comment: /ResetSettings doesn't work.

Comment: What about the steps described on the link?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Steps described also didn't help.

Comment: Do you have the issue if you use /resetuserdata? What happens if you use both /resetsettings and /resetuserdata?

Comment: You are calling the correct instance of devenv.exe by using the full path, right?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I tried /resetuserdata too and it worked as it really cleared ALL settings, however, the problem with broken PropertiesEditor remained. I suggest you just post it as the solution, because the problem seems to be not in any normal VS settings at all, but broken update from Preview 1 to Preview 2. Or a VS 2022 preview feature that applies the settings other than with the standard settings files. I try to reinstall whole VS, then I guess I'll have to wait for the full release or a bug fix.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are 2 switches that you can try to restore the settings to default from the command line:

- `/ResetSettings`: Restores Visual Studio default settings
- `/ResetUserData`: not documented, but it resets the user data to the default values.

```
devenv.exe /ResetSettings
devenv.exe /ResetUserData
```

You can try the `/SafeMode` switch which:

> Starts Visual Studio in safe mode. This switch loads only the default environment, the default services, and the shipped versions of third-party packages.

```
devenv.exe /SafeMode
```

Source: [Devenv command-line switches](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2022)